# iOS: Launching native camera through pure web application via Safari

Tags: ios, web-applications

I am looking for launching native iOS device Camera from a Pure web app(launching thru Safari). Not through any Native or Hybrid frameworks. I wondered how this paste html page http://pastehtml.com/view/chh0dj31e.html
is able to directly access iOS device camera through a pure web application, if i launch this link in device safari. I want to develop the same way.

If anyone has any idea, could you share it with me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following input tag

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

it will show 2 option with take photo and chose existing.

for more info see this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)

Comment: @Catherine Is that any problem with my answer? Why unaccepted?

Comment: This is not working in my HTML code. Button action in a Javascript method in HTML code.

Comment: What error you are getting ? any sample code which you tried? i would suggest to see these links. for examples [link1](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/5/20/Capturing-camerapicture-data-without-PhoneGap) [link2](http://dev.opera.com/articles/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/). For browser compatibility see this [link](http://mobilehtml5.org/)

Comment: I got it now! if we keep this line of code under a button action like that, then it doesn't work..we have to keep this in body itself. Thank you Bluewings Btw.

Comment: Google's docs are especially helpful, containing screenshots of the native UI - [Capturing an Image from the User](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images)